# How to auto load unpacked Edge extension on start?

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

I load unpacked Microsoft Edge extension successfully. But when I restart Edge, it shows:

*We've turned off extensions from unknown sources. They might be risky so we recommend keeping them off.*

There are two buttons: *Turn on anyway*, *Keep them off*. But I want to Keep them on, in other word, I want my extension to be load automatically when browser restart, no need to click the *Turn on anyway* button.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed from Microsoft that unpacked Edge extensions **cannot** be loaded automatically on restart.

> *You can't permanently activate Edge extensions that are not in the Store due to security reasons.*
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/adding-and-removing-extensions

Comment: Of note, Chrome has the same policy. I think Edge is just following status quo here.

Comment: @Xan There is a difference between Edge and Chrome. Edge notify users if they want to **enable** extension, while Chrome notify users if they want to **disable** extension. In Chrome, the extension is actually loaded at launching.

Comment: Interesting; security-wise, that's better (malicious extension already did damage). Utility-wise, that's worse (legit extensions miss opportunities).

Comment: @Xan I agree. I think Edge should allow unpacked extensions to load automatically when user enables Developer features in *about:flags*. That means we are aware of the risks.

Comment: This argument was put forward before. It stops working when it wasn't you who enabled that, and you happily continue unaware of extra malicious extensions. Hence Chrome's stance on "no bypass for this warning"